# In Cypress.io can I copy a content from one element and past it into another one(for example into form)?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I already checked the Cypress.io FAQ: https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-an-element%E2%80%99s-text-contents

And with those tips I tryed by myself but it failed.

I want to get an element, grab it content, put it into variable, and use it later.

I want to achive same result like in Selenium element.getText().

```
describe("Training Test Room Suite", () => {

    it("Copy content from an element and past it  into next one", () => {
        let contentText
        cy.visit("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login");
        cy.get(".example > h2").should(($h2) => {
            contentText = $h2.text()
        })
        cy.get("#username").type(contentText);
    })

})
```

**CypressError:
cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined**

In above code, Im trying to copy text from the H2 , put it in the variable contentText, and paste it into input "username". Everything on a demo application http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login

Can some one help me pls :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a closure issue. Try this:

```
it("Copy content from an element and past it  into next one", () => {
let contentText
cy.visit("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login");
cy.get(".example > h2").should(($h2) => {
  contentText = Cypress.$($h2).text();
    return contentText;
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.get("#username").type(contentText);
});
```

});

Check here the documentation: [cypress then/closures](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#The-number-subject-is-changed-by-returning)